Latexmk: Download a file from the internet
Is it possible to use latexmk to tell it to update the figures from a URL?
My idea is to invoke a subroutine that calls system(wget) when I put something in the CLI. Is that possible?

Duplicate of this or this?

No, the other questions don't mention latexmk, they use LaTeX commands

latexmk provides option -e <code> to execute perl <code> as additional initialization code. For example, if you have a LaTeX file test.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{HeyHo}
\end{document}

and run
latexmk -e 'system("wget https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.png && mv example-image.png HeyHo.png")' --pdf test.tex

on a linux machine, you will get the result:

if the download was successful.
The latexmk output would be something like:
-2024-06-08 20:17:21--  https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.png
Resolving mirrors.ctan.org (mirrors.ctan.org)... 2a03:4000:5e:d33::1, 89.58.7.101
Connecting to mirrors.ctan.org (mirrors.ctan.org)|2a03:4000:5e:d33::1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://de.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.png [following]
--2024-06-08 20:17:21--  https://de.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.png
Resolving de.mirrors.cicku.me (de.mirrors.cicku.me)... 2a06:98c1:3200::90:42, 2a06:98c1:3200::90:40, 2a06:98c1:3200::90:41, ...
Connecting to de.mirrors.cicku.me (de.mirrors.cicku.me)|2a06:98c1:3200::90:42|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4411 (4.3K) [image/png]
Saving to: 'example-image.png'

example-image.png   100%[===================>]   4.31K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2024-06-08 20:17:22 (37.4 MB/s) - 'example-image.png' saved [4411/4411]

Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Apr. 2024. Version 4.85.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required:
    Reason or flag: 'Initial setup'

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "test.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Overfull \hbox (71.49901pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
[][] 

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./Hey
Ho.png>] (./test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2024/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 13104 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'test.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'test.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'test.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (test.pdf) are up-to-date

Instead of system("wget …"), you could also use perl functions for the download and rename, e.g., from LWP module. You can also test for the existence before the download etc.
Instead of typing the whole <code> at the command line, you can store it in a file and use option option -r <rcfile> instead of -e <code>. Both options can be used several times. See the latexmk manual for more information.

Thanks, instead of using system I used getstore and defined a sub to make it easier to run, but this was the gist of it!!
